# Get categories by id

Tags: magento-1.7, category-tree

I'd like to retrive the categories tree excluding some categories of level 2.
Here is my code where I exclude them

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('level', array('eq'=>2))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('nin'=>array($parent_id_to_exclude)))
    ->load()
;
```

Then I imagine to create a foreach loop to retrieve the subcategories, but I have no idea which is the attribute to select the parents.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get child items by filtering on `parent_id`. Optionally there is a resource model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree` that accepts a collection via method `addCollectionData`.

I've never used it to be honest but might help with building the category tree

Comment: using filter on parent_id, I retrive just the first level of a category. Any idea to get all the tree of a particular category? thanks

Comment: `->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like'=> '%/{$parentId}/%'));` might work. That will give all categories that fall under a certain category

Comment: many thanks, I did it using just one foreach loop and adding ->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('nlike'=> "%/$parents_to_exclude/%"))